This contributes to a far lower obesity rate compared to Western countries. => Is this sentence incorrect when comparing "a rate" to "countries"?

This early exposure to balanced diets and mindful eating habits contributes to a far lower obesity rate compared to Western countries.

Is this sentence correct? It seems to be comparing an obesity rate (Japan's rate) to Western countries. What about this version?

This early exposure to balanced diets and mindful eating habits contributes to a far lower obesity rate compared to (or should it be than) those in Western countries.


I don't think it is as direct a comparison as you suggest, and many readers would let it pass.

I agree with the OP’s observations.  We can add those in

This early exposure to balanced diets and mindful eating habits contributes to a far lower obesity rate than/compared to those in Western countries.

or use the possessive countries'

This early exposure to balanced diets and mindful eating habits contributes to a far lower obesity rate than/compared to  Western countries'.

